# How to keep a transformed element behind another element?

Tags: css

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.background {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.foreground {
  color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">B</div>
  <div class="foreground">F</div>
</div>
```

This example is also in here: https://jsfiddle.net/jasajona/vmzfgkcb/
How to keep transformed background div behind foreground? Found several examples but they seems not to work in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `position: relative`to both layers, and then sort them using `z-index` (if `position` is not set, it's considered `static` and `static` does not account for z-indexes)

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.background {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.foreground {
  color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">B</div>
  <div class="foreground">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: position:relative to the second one is enough and no need any z-index

Comment: @TemaniAfif True, but this does make it clear what's going on and what the purpose is tbh.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `transform`ing an element creates a new "stacking context", which supersedes the source order that would otherwise determine which element is on "top".

There are several ways of dealing with this problem, but my favorite way of getting around this strangeness of CSS's z-index calculations is to add an `opacity` property to your foreground element:

```css
.container{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.background {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
} 

.foreground {
  color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">B</div>
  <div class="foreground">F</div>
</div>
```

Here are two resources about `z-index` stacking context:

- https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Why is this your favourite? It's cool that it works (did not know that) but I feel this is kind of hacky, and somebody reading your code later will have to know this to understand it - it just seems very obtuse... (but still, cool)

Comment: `There are several ways of dealing with this problem` --> I don't agree it's a *problem*, it's how CSS works and we need to adjust position/z-index. Position:relative instead of opacity is more suitable in this case

Comment: @somethinghere I find it more flexible in more situations. There are plenty of times when I don't want to change the `position` property of my elements to make them play nicer with `z-index`. `z-index`, because it has no scale, is also prone to creating a pissing contest between unrelated elements, so I try to avoid using it when possible. (ok your `z-index` is `1`; i'll use `2`; ok you used `2` i'll use `10`; ok i'll use `200`, etc...)

Comment: Yeah I'v seen all those issues crop up as well, although that is mostly a planning thing more than anything :) Again, this is pretty cool that it works, I just feel it's so obtuse somebody else would get stuck on your code for a while if they didn't know this... glitch. Also, position `relative` makes no difference compared to `static`, right? Or am I missing some case where it could be an issue?

Comment: Yeah, maybe situations like that are pretty rare, and it's hard to imagine them when we're working with such a simple example as here (I agree just `position:relative` is probably the simpler solution for the given markup). One time you might not be able to change the `position` is if you're already using it to position your elements (see the play problem in my first link). Then, if you still want to avoid `z-index`, you have one less tool to work with, and I go to `opacity` next, but it's really personal preference at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the foreground `position:relative` and it will appear on top like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.background {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}

.foreground {
  color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">B</div>
  <div class="foreground">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply position:relative is enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`isolation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation) property - which creates a new stacking context - on the foreground element.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.background {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.foreground {
  color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  isolation: isolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">B</div>
  <div class="foreground">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @somethinghere Yeah! I hadn't either, but I came across it on MDN as I was reading about z-index.